how to customize a progress bar in android studio (java) with changes in color according to the progress? and for it to look like my description
i am building an app for taking care of a virual animal, and want to indicate to the user how full / hungry it is by using a progress bar.
I want the progress bar to be horizontal, with a brown outline, round edges, to the inner part to be green when above 40% and red when below it (includes).
I tried to code it and even use chatGPT but with no sucsess...
this is the code that i (and chatGPT wrote):
custom_progress_bar.xml:
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
            <stroke
                android:width="10dp"
                android:color="#614328" />
            <corners android:radius="50dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#238A23" />
                <corners android:radius="30dp" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>

and the progress bar in the screen's xml:
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/PBfullness"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="100"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_bar" />

i was expecting it to work but it just looks like a really thick green blob.
i would really thank if anyone can help me make my code work, and/or help me understand why is it not working.

You might want to create a custom View for that.
Below is an example of the simplest custom ProgressView. I recommend that you also override onMeasure to support wrap_content.
class CustomProgressView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    val borderWidth = context.dpToPx(2).toFloat()
    val progressHeight = context.dpToPx(8).toFloat()
    val progressHeight2 = progressHeight / 2
    val rect = RectF()
    val paint = Paint()

    var progress: Float = 0.3f
        set(value) {
            field = value.coerceIn(0f, 1f)
            invalidate()
        }


    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        rect.set(0f, 0f, width.toFloat(), progressHeight)
        paint.color = Color.LTGRAY // grey for background
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, progressHeight2, progressHeight2, paint)
        rect.set(0f, 0f, width * progress, progressHeight)
        paint.color = Color.BLUE // brown
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, progressHeight2, progressHeight2, paint)
        rect.set(borderWidth, borderWidth, (width - borderWidth * 2) * progress, progressHeight - borderWidth)
        paint.color = if (progress <= 0.4f) Color.RED // red
        else Color.GREEN // green
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, progressHeight2, progressHeight2, paint)
    }

    private fun Context.dpToPx(dp: Int) =
        TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            dp.toFloat(),
            resources.displayMetrics
        ).toInt()
}

40% Example 60% Example
